# Why is there a Nepali poster in Boku no Hero Academia?

Tags: my-hero-academia

I was curious as to why the animators would use a language other than Japanese and English, given the fact that no one in Japan understands Nepali. This is from season 2 episode 15. The Nepali in the poster means "cat". Does anyone have any idea why is it here?

[image]

Comment: I just want to point out though that Nepali and Hindi are different languages

Comment: Yes I know. Hindi is one of my native languages but anyway these two are not so far apart languages they both are almost mutually intelligible to their respective natives.

Comment: Given that this question has received at least two "answers" that only say "that's Nepali, not Hindi", without actually trying to answer the question, *and* given that the question already acknowledges that the poster is actually in Nepali, I've submitted an edit to remove any reference to Hindi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would dispute your claim that:

> ... no one in Japan understands Hindi

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indians_in_Japan), the population of Indians living in Japan as of 2017 is **30,048**. Given that Hindi is one of the official languages of India, I would imagine that a good portion of them speak it.

This is quite a small chunk of the population (the population of Japan is 127,084,082 [as of 2018](http://worldpopulationreview.com/countries/japan-population/), making 0.024% of the Japanese population Indian migrants), but it is still not an insignificant amount.

I'm from Canada, and I see signs in other languages all the time around my city. There are often small pockets of people from other countries living in communities, and as a result, there is bound to be some signage catered to them.

The animators may have added this for any number of reasons - perhaps as a nod to Indian fans watching the show, or simply for some interesting background imagery.

Comment: I see. Well, obviously by "no one" I meant no significant population. It's something just not expected. :P Thanks!

Comment: @シャシュワト Fair enough. I hope my answer was helpful!